# Upload ipython notebook directly to github

Tags: python, github

Is there a way to directly upload ipython notebooks to github. my current workflow is:

1) download the ipynb

2) open in gedit, copy

3) go to gist at github, paste, copy url

4) go to nbviewer.ipython.org, paste

Comment: What are you trying to do with the above workflow?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). If you are looking for a software product, please [edit] your question and point out its requirements. For a guide, please check with [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Open a github account and remember your **username**
2. Create a **public** project in your accounts and remember the **project_name**
3. `git clone` the project to a local directory
4. `cd` to the same directory
5. `ipython notebook`
6. Develop and test your notebook, remembering to save before exit
7. `git add` *the name of your notebook*
8. `git commit -m"`*Description of your change* `"` to remember what the change was
9. `git push`
10. Go to http://nbviewer.ipython.org/ and enter **username/project_name**
11. Repeat steps 5..10 as necessary

Of course if you are just trying to convert your local or saved notebook to a webpage then just:

```
ipython nbconvert nbname.ipynb
```

On your command line.

If, however, you are looking at other peoples, public, notebooks then there are a couple of browser extensions [here](http://jiffyclub.github.io/open-in-nbviewer/) that can open them in the online nbviewer in a single click.